# Wildfly - why there are differences in app between debug and normal mode

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss7.x, wildfly

I don't understand what's wrong.

When I run my war application in eclipse on wildfly 8.0.0 Final in **debug mode**, then everything works fine. But when I switch wildfly to **normal mode**, then it doesn't take into account some annotations and errors appear.

Especially I cannot manage to start working @Transactional annotation in normal mode.

E.g. such code:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Transactional
public class CmpNoteCrud extends BaseCrud<ComNote> {

    @Override
    public String remove(ComNote inst) {
        this.inst = inst;
        inst = entityManager.find(ComNote.class, inst.getId());
        return super.remove(inst);
    }
}
```

in debug mode works fine, but in normal mode throws me an error:

```
06:05:55,011 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

Is there any configuration I missed?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `tmp` directory?